# Slack API email_domain always blank

Tags: slack-api

I'm using the Slack API method [team.info](https://api.slack.com/methods/team.info/test), yet it seems to always be blank for all the teams I've tested it on.  Is there no way to get the domain name of a team without using the [users.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list) method to look at individual email addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a example response for the [`team.info`](https://api.slack.com/methods/team.info) method:

```
 {
     "ok": true,
     "team": {
         "id": "T12345",
         "name": "My Team",
         "domain": "example",
         "email_domain": "example.com",
         "icon": {
             "image_34": "https:\/\/...",
             "image_44": "https:\/\/...",
             "image_68": "https:\/\/...",
             "image_88": "https:\/\/...",
             "image_102": "https:\/\/...",
             "image_132": "https:\/\/...",
             "image_default": true
         },
        "enterprise_id": "E1234A12AB",
        "enterprise_name": "Umbrella Corporation"
     }
 }
```

The property `email_domain` contains a white list of domain names that people can use to sign-up on your slack and without needing an invitation. This is turned off by default and then this property will be empty.

The domain name of your Slack team can be found under the `domain` property. This is never empty. The full domain in this example would be `example.slack.com`.

Looking at the email addresses of your users may not always work, because people can use any email address for sign-up when invited.